# How to order the links of different pages in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to figure out how this links should be composed in order to be useful.
Normally in cakePhP i make new pages and it links to each other like this .
    soemthing.com/Places/catergory
But I want it to appear like this  Places/category/{name of Place}/{id of the service type}

So in my controller in cake php I wrote this

```
     public function category($city){



    $data = array('place' => $city);
    $this -> set('services',$this -> Service -> find('all', array('conditions' => array('Service.place' => $city))));
    $this -> set($data);

    }
```

But its not working, so anyone has any idea about this, need help ,
I am new to cake PHP so pretend your answering a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public function category($city=null,$type=null){
    $conditions = array('Service.place' => $city,'Service.type' => $type);
    $services = $this -> Service -> find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)));
    $this -> set(compact('services','city');
}
```

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/places/category/*', array('controller'=>'services','action'=>'category'));
```

Comment: Hey Salines thanks for your help but i got closer to my objective by changing it a bit more , 
public function category($city=null,$type=null){
   $conditions = array('Service.place' => $city, 'Service.activity_id' => $id);
   $services = $this -> Service -> find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)));
   $this -> set(compact('services','city');
}
But there is still something missing could you help me out with it ...